# How to get start point and end point (properties) of a hittest line

Tags: line, hittest

I want to select and move a line on a canvas. I got the line using hittest but I don't know how to move the line. I created a New SelectedVisual for line and used a DrawingContext to drawline. But I don't know how to get the start point and end point of the visual because there is no such methods. Is there any way to shift or move the visual?